# Is there anyway to customize the values in `aws-exports.js` with AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I want to customize the `src/aws-exports.js` file, i.e. add my own values to it:

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "ap-southeast-2",
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket": ...",
    "foo": "bar",
};
```

I have no idea how I can get the `"foo": "bar"` entry in there. I have looked into modifying the `team-provider-info.json` file with extra entries but that doesn't seem to work.

Basically my use case is I have other key value pairs for environments, and I wanted to piggyback off what Amplify has already done so I don't need to add yet another tool for managing environments.

If I can't find a solution to this I will probably just use `npm` some how.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. That file is autogenerated every time `amplify push/publish` is run, I think `amplify env pull/checkout` updates it too. I even didn't include it into version control.

Comment: Yeah looks a bit locked down, I've been playing with the ability to create extensions in amplify, after looking through the source code, I have figured I could make an extension command which would do this, but it would as you say, get overriden every time I would do an update.